# Find user's current location(latitude and longitude) when user logged in, through Facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

does Facebook api provides user's current location(latitude and longitude) when user logged in ? If yes, then how do I get it ? https://graph.facebook.com/me/ provides only user related data, but not the current location. Please help me to get this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user facebook document,I got the current location with latitude and longitude. To get this we need to fire a query which will select current location from user table with user's access token.

FQL(Facebook Query Language) :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT current_location FROM user WHERE uid=me()& access_token=xxxxx
```

Response:

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "current_location": {
        "city": <city name>,
        "state": <state name>,
        "country": <country name >,
        "zip": <zip code>,
        "latitude": <latitude>,
        "longitude": <longitude>,
        "id": <location id>,
        "name": <address>
     }
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find Find user's location(latitude and longitude) on base its profile details when user logged in, through Facebook api? Then Follow this:

1. Download https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk 
   and copy all files from src and put in your project folder and rename it to php-sdk
2. ## Your code file(index.php)

   require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

   $config = array(
     'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',

   'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',

   'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
   );

   $facebook = new Facebook($config);

   $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

   $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

   $query = 'SELECT current_location FROM user WHERE uid = me()';

   $response = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $query));

   print_r($response);

OutPut:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [current_location] => Array
                (
                    [city] => Test
                    [state] => Test
                    [country] => Test
                    [zip] => 
                    [latitude] => 53.0833
                    [longitude] => 92.6667
                    [id] => 4555555878787887
                    [name] => Test
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with facebook FQL query.
Please refer below link 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/standard_user_info/